# Indexing datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, indexing, datetimeindex

I imported a csv file in python. Then, I changed the first column to datetime format.

```
datetime                  Bid32    Ask32

2019-01-01 22:06:11.699  1.14587  1.14727  
2019-01-01 22:06:12.634  1.14567  1.14707  
2019-01-01 22:06:13.091  1.14507  1.14647
```

I saw three ways for indexing first column.

```
df.index = df.datetime
del datetime
```

or

```
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

and

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex('datetime'), inplace=True)
```

My question is about the second and third ways. Why in some sources they used `pd.DatetimeIndex()` with `df.set_index()` (like third code) while the second code was enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are not changing the 'datetime' column with `to_datetime()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime', 'Bid32', 'Ask32'])
df.loc[0] = ['2019-01-01 22:06:11.699', '1.14587', '1.14727']

df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)  # option 2
print(type(df.index))
```

Result: 
`pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`

vs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime', 'Bid32', 'Ask32'])
df.loc[0] = ['2019-01-01 22:06:11.699', '1.14587', '1.14727']

df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']), inplace=True)  # option 3
print(type(df.index))
```

Result: 
`pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`

So the third one with `pd.DatetimeIndex()` makes it an actual datetime index, which is what you want.

Documentation:

[pandas.Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html)

[pandas.DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

Comment: I examined in your way. With `datetime64` column format, your first method gives the same result that you get in your second method.  Thanks